# Compare time with mobile time

Tags: android, listview

I have Two timings and one button in my listview.Difference between them is 10 min.Wat I want is when my mobile time reaches newtime button must get clickable until then it cannot be clicked.Following is my code-

**SecondCustom.java**

```
public class SecondCustom extends BaseAdapter {
    Activity a;
    ArrayList<Model> timelist;
    Date newtime;
    Time itime,canceltime;


    public SecondCustom(Activity a, ArrayList<Model> timelist) {
        this.a = a;
        this.timelist= timelist;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return timelist.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int i) {
        return timelist.get(i);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int i) {
        return i;
    }



    public class Viewholder{
        TextView srno, ctime, ltime;
        Button buy;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int i, View convertView, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
        Viewholder viewholder=null;
        if (convertView == null) {
            viewholder = new Viewholder();
            LayoutInflater li = a.getLayoutInflater();
            convertView = li.inflate(R.layout.secondcustom, viewGroup, false);

            viewholder.srno = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.sr);
            viewholder.ctime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.currenttime);



            viewholder.buy = (Button) convertView.findViewById(R.id.st);
            viewholder.ltime = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lefttime);
            convertView.setTag(viewholder);
        }
        else {
            viewholder = (Viewholder) convertView.getTag();
        }


        Model model=timelist.get(i);
        viewholder.srno.setText(valueOf(timelist.get(i).getSr()));



        String Time = DateFormat.getTimeInstance().format(new Date());
        viewholder.ctime.setText(Time);

     Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
        SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("HH:mm:ss a");

        cal.add(Calendar.MINUTE,10); 
     String FutTime= sd.format(cal.getTime());
        viewholder.ltime.setText(FutTime);


        viewholder.buy.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(a, "Purchased" + " " + flowerlist.get(i).getSr(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                }
            });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

**secondcustom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="horizontal" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">


    <TextView
        android:layout_width="50dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/sr"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/currenttime"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>

    <Button
        android:layout_width="70dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/st"
        android:text="Buy"
        android:textAllCaps="false"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:background="#57ba58"
        android:textAlignment="center"
        android:layout_marginTop="5dp"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp"/>

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="100dp"
        android:layout_height="40dp"
        android:id="@+id/lefttime"
        android:textSize="15dp"
        android:textAlignment="center"/>


</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use handler to make button clickable after 10 minutes.

Pseudo code should look like this -

```
new Handler().postDelayed(new Runnable() {
              public void run() {
               viewholder.buy.setclickable(true);

            }
        }, 10*60*1000);
```

Comment: It ll lag the UI dude.

Comment: This solution works until app is in background.But if app is closed then timer restarts again.I want even if app is closed after 10 mins only it must get clicked.

Comment: You can dump your list in sqlite and add one column to keep track of time. You can then update time column in db along with listview button using Handler, Timer etc ticking every second. Even if timer get killed your last time will persist in db and you can trigger count down from last saved duratio n on restart of app.

Answer (score 0):

```
new CountDownTimer(30000, 1000) {

    public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {
        mTextField.setText("seconds remaining: " + millisUntilFinished / 1000);
       //here you can have your logic to set text to edittext
    }

    public void onFinish() {
        mTextField.setText("done!");
    }

}.start();
```

Use countDownTimer for your requirement. When your timer finish it ll give event onFinish(). On that you can perform your operations.

Answer (score 0):

A countdown timer may be solve your problem.Set a countdown timer for sleepTime 10sec

```
viewholder.buy.setclickable(false);
mCountDownTimer = new CountDownTimer(sleepTime, 1000) {

                public void onTick(long millisUntilFinished) {


                    String hms = String.format("%02d:%02d:%02d", TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.HOURS.toMinutes(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toHours(millisUntilFinished)),
                            TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toSeconds(millisUntilFinished) - TimeUnit.MINUTES.toSeconds(TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS.toMinutes(millisUntilFinished)));
                    txtTimer.setText(hms);//display the time 
                }
                public void onFinish() {
                    txtTimer.setText("00:00:00");
                    viewholder.buy.setclickable(true);

                }
            }.start();
```

Comment: countdown timer has one problem if we remove app from background then timer is stopped and reset when app is started again so didnt want to implement it.

Comment: you can try  alarmintent